# Search Account Based on Name field

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I want to query on account fields such that if i search using alphabets on vf page it must show account name based on starting Letter not in between lt has to search.How can I do This?

```
<apex:page Controller="AccountSearch">
   <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" >

     <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
           <apex:outputLabel for="searchText">Search Text</apex:outputLabel>
           <apex:panelGroup >
              <apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}"/>
             <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!doSearch}" 
                                rerender="showmsg"   status="status"/>
           </apex:panelGroup>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="requesting..."/>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Results" id="results" columns="1">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" 
                           rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(results))}">
          <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!a.phone}"/>

       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg" />
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

```
 public class AccountSearch {
 String searchText;
// List<Account> results;
 public list <Account> acc {get;set;}


  public String getSearchText() {
     return searchText;
  }

   public void setSearchText(String s) {
     searchText = s;
   }

   public List<Account> getResults() {
     return acc;
   }


  public PageReference doSearch() { 
     searchText = searchText +'%';  
       if(searchText.length() >= 2  ){
       string searchquery='select Name,industry,phone from account where name like  :searchText ';
       acc= Database.query(searchquery);
          // acc= (List<Account>)[FIND :searchText RETURNING Account(Name, Industry, Phone)][0];          
           }
            if (acc.isEmpty()){
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new 
        ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'No Results Found'));
       }
       return null;

     }
   }
```

Comment: What is the issue with the current code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i want name values  of account records to be searched starting letter of each account values and it should not search in between like I have account values

acc1,
Test1
Test 3
so if i search using st or cc it should not have to search 
and if i search using ac or Te it must search and return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your query in `doSearch()` as:

```
searchText = searchText +'%';
string query='select Name,industry,phone from account where name like :searchText';
acc= Database.query(searchquery);
```

I recommend to use static soql as:

```
acc = [select Name,industry,phone from account where name like :searchText];
```

Comment: Hi @reshma How can i remove % character from VF page